# Cordova: Why cordova-plugin-market is being fetched every time?

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have added the plugin to local, but every time, it still fetch it from npm. However, I didn't see anyother plugin is querying npm.

Every time I build the project, it shows:

```
Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-market" in config.xml. Installing to the project
Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-market@1.1" via npm
Plugin "com.xmartlabs.cordova.market" already installed on android.
Plugin "com.xmartlabs.cordova.market" already installed on browser.
```

Comment: Was the plugin installation successful the very first time you did? Also just curious, why is this plugin used?

Comment: @Kailas yes, it did. I need to open android market.

Comment: Did you check the fetch.json for the entry is there or not for this corresponding plugin? It's in plugins folder.